# 404 When making POST request using Retrofit

Tags: android, rest, post, retrofit2

I have the following API call I created using Retrofit2:

```
@Headers({"Accept: application/json", "Content-Type: application/json"})
@POST("task/create/")
Call<StandardTaskResponse> createNewTask(@Body Task newTask);
```

and I try to use that method like so:

```
Task newTask = new Task(name, description, "", null, USER, 4, priority, null, null);

      Call<StandardTaskResponse> call = HavocService.getInstance().getHavocAPI().createNewTask(newTask);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<StandardTaskResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<StandardTaskResponse> call, Response<StandardTaskResponse> response) {
                LogUtil.v("Response message: " + response.message());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<StandardTaskResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                LogUtil.e(t.getCause().getMessage());
            }
        });
```

This is what the logs show:

```
10-16 19:08:07.963 10511-10894/io.havoc.todo D/OkHttp: --> POST http://ec2-amazonaws-base-url-redacted.com:3000/api/task/create/ http/1.1
10-16 19:08:07.964 10511-10894/io.havoc.todo D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json
10-16 19:08:07.964 10511-10894/io.havoc.todo D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 124
10-16 19:08:07.964 10511-10894/io.havoc.todo D/OkHttp: Accept: application/json
10-16 19:08:07.964 10511-10894/io.havoc.todo D/OkHttp: {"category":"","description":"H","indexInList":4,"name":"H","priority":"HIGH","user":"57a7bd24-ddf0-5c24-9091-ba331e486dc7"}
10-16 19:08:07.964 10511-10894/io.havoc.todo D/OkHttp: --> END POST (124-byte body)
10-16 19:08:07.969 10511-10516/io.havoc.todo I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=23KB, data=29KB
10-16 19:08:07.969 10511-10516/io.havoc.todo I/art: After code cache collection, code=23KB, data=29KB
10-16 19:08:07.969 10511-10516/io.havoc.todo I/art: Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
10-16 19:08:07.999 10511-10894/io.havoc.todo D/OkHttp: <-- 404 Not Found http://ec2-amazonaws-base-url-redacted.com:3000/api/task/create/ (34ms)
10-16 19:08:07.999 10511-10894/io.havoc.todo D/OkHttp: content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
10-16 19:08:07.999 10511-10894/io.havoc.todo D/OkHttp: cache-control: no-cache
10-16 19:08:07.999 10511-10894/io.havoc.todo D/OkHttp: vary: accept-encoding
10-16 19:08:07.999 10511-10894/io.havoc.todo D/OkHttp: Date: Sun, 16 Oct 2016 23:07:59 GMT
10-16 19:08:07.999 10511-10894/io.havoc.todo D/OkHttp: Connection: keep-alive
10-16 19:08:07.999 10511-10894/io.havoc.todo D/OkHttp: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
10-16 19:08:08.020 10511-10894/io.havoc.todo D/OkHttp: {"statusCode":404,"error":"Not Found"}
10-16 19:08:08.020 10511-10894/io.havoc.todo D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (38-byte body)
10-16 19:08:08.050 10511-10511/io.havoc.todo V/(NewTaskActivityPresenter.java:40): Response message: Not Found
```

I have searched around on other StackOverflow answers and the common suspect is the base URL. Mine is accessed like so:

`private static final String HAVOC_URI = "http://ec2-amazonaws-base-url-redacted.com:3000/api/";`.

The body for this API call is just supposed to be the `Task` I want to create. The response is supposed to be something of the form:

```
{
    "status":true,
    "doc":{
        "_id":"5801175bc5c3f451301fd235",
        "t_id":"8671fc295bc9",
        "name":"Do calculus homework",
        "description":"Finish all assigned homework from chapters 1 and 2",
        "category":"test",
        "indexInList":0,
        "priority":3,
        "dateDue":1477291500000,
        "user":"57a",
        "status":"ARCHIVED",
        "__v":0,
        "subtasks":[
            {
                "name":"Finish Chapter 1 - Derivatives",
                "isCompleted":false
            },
            {
                "name":"Finish Chapter 1 - Integrals",
                "isCompleted":false
            },
            {
                "name":"Finish Chapter 2 - Graphing",
                "isCompleted":false
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Which is: `status`: whether or not there was an error on the backend, `doc:` task that was just created

I have no clue why this is happening. I'm certain the base URL is correct. I can actually use a [REST API test app from the Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sn.restandroid) and do a POST request with an empty body and the response is correct. It's only when I attempt this on Android do I get this error.

I'd appreciate any and all help.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I'm an idiot. I needed to remove the ending backslash for the `@POST` parameter.

```
@Headers({"Accept: application/json", "Content-Type: application/json"})
@POST("task/create")
Call<StandardTaskResponse> createNewTask(@Body Task newTask);
```